Castle's poker buddies: Who's the lady?
In S01E01 of Castle, Rick is playing poker with other (real life) authors:

Going by Wikia, the guy with the glasses is James Patterson. The chap on the right is Stephen J. Cannell (and the one with his back to the camera is Rick himself). Who's the lady on the left and who's the blonde (that I don't remember seeing)?
EXTERNAL EDIT: Here's a better picture of the brunette. She's definitely the dealer.


The only thing I can find says that "the woman" is just a dealer.

@JohnP I wondered if they were perhaps other writers or alternatively, the wives of Patterson and Cannell.

Unless you can get ahold of one of the writers, I don't know a way to tell. I went to my usual sites and a couple obscure fan sites and that's the best I could find. Although the blond does bear a resemblance to Kym Jackson, I don't think that's her.

She looks like the author allison brennon

The blond is actress Kym Jackson according imdb.com
(IMDB credits Kym Jackson with playing the (uncredited) murder victim, Allison Tisdale.)
The brunette seems to have been a uncredited extra who has the misfortune of not having her role documented. She is not a writer nor a television producer like Patterson or Cannell.

I'm wondering if the female poke player is Carol Higgins Clark?  This is a link to a photo of her with her mom in 2011:

From here.

No way... the distance between the eyes is completely different.

Looks kinda like Sue Grafton, writer of the Alphabet series featuring private-eye Kinsey Millhone. Grafton was once a TV writer, which is why she has an aversion to her books being "picked up" for script treatments.

The hair is very different and she looks younger than Grafton. It could always be a wig, but this quote from the show's creator a year after this episode (3rd paragraph) means Grafton hadn't appeared on the show yet.
